# How can I implement the logout button in web page?

Tags: tomcat, authentication, logout

I am trying create a simple "login" / "logout" page.

The server side is running Tomcat.

By following [This Link](http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/tomcat-security.html), I successfully utilise the internal authentication mechanism of Tomcat to let user login.

But how can I implement the "logout" button? What should I do if the user click the "logout" button? How can I tell Tomcat that user wants to logout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logout Link/Button must do following things:

1. `invalidate()` the `session`.
2. Clear up the `cookies` (if any).
3. Reset the `bean` object (if any).
4. Get redirected to custom logout message page or home page of application.

Also if any database value is related to user's *login/logout* then set it to appropriate value.

Below are some answers that may help you further:

- [JSF life after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148320/803285)
- [Session handling on J2EE application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5495361/803285)
- [How to invalidate session in JSF 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620582/803285)